# ReportViewer- Devexpress, al exportar a XLS se pierden los totales

Tags: devexpress

```html
<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.XtraReports.v17.1.Web, Version=17.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" namespace="DevExpress.XtraReports.Web" tagprefix="dx" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[

        function ValidarKey(e) {
            var theEvent = e.htmlEvent || window.event;
            var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;

            if (key != 8 && key != 9) {
                key = String.fromCharCode(key);
                var regex = /[0-9]|\./;

                if (!regex.test(key)) {
                    theEvent.returnValue = false;
                    if (theEvent.preventDefault)
                        theEvent.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        }
                
    // ]]> 
    </script>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="obsDepartamento" runat="server" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="TraerDepartamentos" 
        TypeName="Servicios.ProcesosMaestros">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:top">
                <dx:ASPxRoundPanel ID="ASPxRoundPanel1" HeaderText="Filtros" runat="server" Theme="BlackGlass"
                    Width="200px">
                    <PanelCollection>
                        <dx:PanelContent>
                            <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblAnio" runat="server" Text="Año:"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                            <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txbAnio" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="txbAnio" Width="100%">
                                <MaskSettings Mask="9999" PromptChar="Y" />
                            </dx:ASPxTextBox>
                            <dx:ASPxLabel ID="LblDepartamento" runat="server" Text="Departamento:">
                            </dx:ASPxLabel>
                            <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cboDepartamento" runat="server" DataSourceID="obsDepartamento"
                                TextField="NombreDepartamento" IncrementalFilteringMode="StartsWith" DropDownStyle="DropDown"
                                ClientInstanceName="cboDepartamento" Theme="BlackGlass" ValueField="IdDepartamento"
                                EnableSynchronization="False">
                            </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                            <br />
                            <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnBuscar" runat="server" Text="Buscar" AutoPostBack="true">
                            </dx:ASPxButton>
                        </dx:PanelContent>
                    </PanelCollection>
                </dx:ASPxRoundPanel>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top">
                <dx:ReportToolbar ID="rtbReportePresupuestoAnualConsolidado" runat="server" 
                    ReportViewerID="rpvReportePresupuestoAnualConsolidado" ShowDefaultButtons="False" Theme="BlackGlass">
                    <Items>
                        <dx:ReportToolbarButton ItemKind="Search" />
                        <dx:ReportToolbarSeparator />
                        <dx:ReportToolbarButton ItemKind="PrintReport" />
                        <dx:ReportToolbarButton ItemKind="PrintPage" />
                        <dx:ReportToolbarSeparator />
                        <dx:ReportToolbarButton Enabled="False" ItemKind="FirstPage" />
                        <dx:ReportToolbarButton Enabled="False" ItemKind="PreviousPage" />
                        <dx:ReportToolbarLabel ItemKind="PageLabel" />
                        <dx:ReportToolbarComboBox ItemKind="PageNumber" Width="65px">
                        </dx:ReportToolbarComboBox>
                        <dx:ReportToolbarLabel ItemKind="OfLabel" />
                        <dx:ReportToolbarTextBox IsReadOnly="True" ItemKind="PageCount" />
                        <dx:ReportToolbarButton ItemKind="NextPage" />
                        <dx:ReportToolbarButton ItemKind="LastPage" />
                        <dx:ReportToolbarSeparator />
                        <dx:ReportToolbarButton ItemKind="SaveToDisk" />
                        <dx:ReportToolbarButton ItemKind="SaveToWindow" />
                        <dx:ReportToolbarComboBox ItemKind="SaveFormat" Width="70px">
                            <elements>
                                <dx:ListElement Value="pdf" />
                                <dx:ListElement Value="xls" />
                                <dx:ListElement Value="xlsx" />
                                <dx:ListElement Value="rtf" />
                                <dx:ListElement Value="mht" />
                                <dx:ListElement Value="html" />
                                <dx:ListElement Value="txt" />
                                <dx:ListElement Value="csv" />
                                <dx:ListElement Value="png" />
                            </elements>
                        </dx:ReportToolbarComboBox>
                    </Items>
                    <styles>
                        <LabelStyle>
                        <Margins MarginLeft='3px' MarginRight='3px' />
                        </LabelStyle>
                    </styles>
                </dx:ReportToolbar>
                <dx:ReportViewer ID="rpvReportePresupuestoAnualConsolidado" runat="server" Theme="Default" ReportName="ReportePresupuestoAnualConsolidado">
                </dx:ReportViewer>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Hola chicos soy nuevo en esto, y estoy resolviendo un misterio, resulta que tengo un reporte en **Devexpress** el cual me permite exportarlo en diferentes formatos.

El tema es que cuando lo exporto en PDF, la columna de totales me la muestra correctamente.
[image: Totales en PDF]

Pero cuando lo exporto en formato XLS los totales se pierden:

[image: Totales en XLS]

Cabe aclarar que es el mismo reporte, solo que en PDF me muestra los totales y en Excel no.

Agradezco de antemano su amable ayuda!!

Comment: Por favor agrega el codigo actual que tienes para que te podamos ayudar

Comment: ¿El problema solamente ocurre al exportar en `xls` o también en `xlsx`?

Comment: Hola,  gracias por tu ayuda, si efectivamente ocurre con ambos (xls y xlsx)